# How to export custom post type with ACF to individual file with automation?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, advanced-custom-fields, export, scheduled-posts

I have a custom post type `product` using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)

I would like to schedule a daily cron task automation to export all `published` posts into `post_id.txt`, one for each post.

I know there are plugins that can export custom post type and ACF to CSV or XML.

But my requirement is a more customized task.

A simplified example, the format of the output file `post_id.txt` should be and each field separated by `\n`:

eg. `1234.txt`

```
POST_TITLE
PRODUCT_IMAGE(ACF URL FIELD)
CATEGORY
TAGS
CONTENT
```

I can access all these information in the template loop, but how do I write a function to export them as the above job requirement?

Any pointer and direction of where to begin is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule your backup with WP Cron - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

In the cron event, run your query for posts or CPTs and be sure to add  `'numberposts'       => -1,` to return all.

When you loop through your posts from the resulting query, push the values to an array `$data[]=$some_string_data_for_prop;`

- https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post

And when you're ready to write the data, convert the array values to a single string; `$output = implode("\n", $data);`

Then write the data to a file `file_put_contents($filepath, $output);`

Comment: All the steps make sense to me.  I'm using a W3 Total Cache and I use the system cronjob for my wp-cron execution to ensure it's running at my scheduled time.  The thing I'm not sure is where do I put the actual code?  In my template file or in functions.php?  Or can I create a separate .php file for this task or even making it a dedicated plugin?  In this case, how do I use the Wordpress functions if it's a standalone file?

Comment: It's tricky, you can put it in functions.php but you really only want to turn on/off the event. It's probably best to make it as a plugin (since it's not theme related) and have a button that starts/stops the process.

Comment: Yes, it's unrelated to theme but I find the theme's loop is the easiest to implment.  I understand the logic here, just not sure where do get started.  Any pointer to instruction on writing a simple basic plugin?

Comment: Plugins are pretty easy. It's a file with the same name as the folder in /wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/your-plugin.php - http://wppb.me - https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin